# Check if internet is sending/receiving packets using JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, wifi

I have been making some HTML code to tell me the status of my internet, I have offline and online events set up but I want to check if my internet's sending or receiving packets. How would I do this using JavaScript? I checked everywhere but I can't figure out how to do this in JavaScript. (Thanks in advance!)

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onoffline="myFunction(); myFunction12();" ononline="myFunction1(); myFunction02();"
onpacketsend="myFunction2(); setTimeout(() => {myFunction22}, 300);">

<h3 id="demo1">Online.</h3>

<h3 id="demo2">Sending/Recieving...</h3>

<h3 id="demo">Offline!</h3>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
}

function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("demo1").style.color = "green";
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("demo2").style.color = "blue";
}


function myFunction02() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "black";
}

function myFunction12() {
  document.getElementById("demo1").style.color = "black";
}

function myFunction22() {
  document.getElementById("demo2").style.color = "black";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the `packetsend` event? Are you trying to determine whether your HTML page is sending/receiving packets or for the computer in general? Know that the latter is not possible with frontend JavaScript.

Comment: It's a placeholder for the actual event.Ok, how do I do it then?

Comment: So were you going for option A or B?

Comment: B, unfortunatly.

Comment: You'll need to create a software on the user's computer to intercept all requests, I'm afraid, then notify your frontend. Are you certain you need this functionality?

Comment: Can you link me to a tutorial? It's not a public page so I can do any local stuff I want.  No I guess I don't need it but it would be nice.

Comment: I guess I could use 'A', how do I do that?

Comment: You won't be able to go very far, but you could create a service worker to intercept fetch events.

Comment: I'm still usure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to do with Javascript/HTML. Unfortunatly this means you can only check to see if you are connected to the internet

so I can only:

```
<body onoffline="myFunction();" ononline="myFunction1();"
">
```